# Grails nested tags

Tags: grails

I have been searching all over the internet also in documentations about nested tags for parent/child relation but I got nothing so far. What I want to learn is, is there anyway for such a custom "parent" tag to know about its "children"

```
<mytag:parent source="${somelist}">
    <mytag:child column="name" style="padding-left:10px">
    </mytag>
    <mytag:child column="surname" style="padding-left:10px">
    </mytag>
</mytag>
```

In this example parent tag gets the collection and children prints their given columns by calling `somelist.name` and `somelist.surname` respectively. Do I have to parse the DOM to learn about children or can I reach the children somehow in "groovy" code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<mytag:parent>` should put own context/data as a request scope attribute (or page scope), process it by `<mytag:child>`, and remove it on closing tag. Like:

```
static final CONTEXT = this.class.name

def parent = { attrs, body ->
    def data = [
        name: 'test 1',
        surname: 'test 2'  // i guess you want to load this values from attr.source
    ]
    request.setAttribute(CONTEXT, data)
    out << body.call()
    request.removeAttribute(CONTEXT)
}


def child = { attrs, body ->
   def data = request.getAttribute(CONTEXT)
   out << 'name: '
   out << data.name  
   out << 'surname: '
   out << data.surname  
}
```

Comment: This throws the exception as Class
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException
Message
No signature of method: org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.removeAttribute() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [java.lang.Class, [x:1, name:test]] Possible solutions: removeAttribute(java.lang.String)

Comment: First of all thanks for your help but this code prints nothing on the screen when it is called as <mytag:parent><mytag:child></mytag:child></mytag:parent>.

Comment: Yes, there was a mistakem, fixed. btw, i'm sure that you got the idea, it's not final and ready to use version, just proof of concept